# Select related Row without comparing Street Name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table "Address". It has three columns "ID", "SameAsID", "Street"

```
  ID     SameAsID           Street     
  --------------------------------------------
  1                          88 happy ave
  2         1                88 happy ave
  3         1                88 happy ave
  4         3                88 happy ave
  5         3                88 happy ave
  6         3                88 happy ave
  7                          11 lucky street
  8         7                11 lucky street
  9         7                11 lucky street
  10        6                88 happy ave
  11        5                88 happy ave
```

Now, I want to select all the ID related to ID = 1 but DON'T COMPARE STREET COLUMN, it will output following
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11

How to write this SQL WITHOUT COMPARING STREET COLUMN?

Comment: Come on - when you're asking for assistance with a homework question you need to show you've made some sort of effort.

Comment: this is not a homework question. I just simplify the question. I need to write a stored procedure to update all Street if the street of root ID was changed.

Comment: I real need a help.

Comment: Why have you made it a requirement to not compare the street column?

Comment: because the street name is editable in UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic hierarchical query. You said you want the id's only; if needed, you can select `id`, `sameasid` and `street`, it will make no difference.

Notice the test data entered in a `with` clause. This is not part of the solution; the query is just five lines.

```
with
     address ( ID, SameAsID, Street ) as (     
       select  1, null, '88 happy ave'    from dual union all
       select  2,    1, '88 happy ave'    from dual union all
       select  3,    1, '88 happy ave'    from dual union all
       select  4,    3, '88 happy ave'    from dual union all
       select  5,    3, '88 happy ave'    from dual union all
       select  6,    3, '88 happy ave'    from dual union all
       select  7, null, '11 lucky street' from dual union all
       select  8,    7, '11 lucky street' from dual union all
       select  9,    7, '11 lucky street' from dual union all
       select 10,    6, '88 happy ave'    from dual union all
       select 11,    5, '88 happy ave'    from dual
     )
--  End of test data (not part of SQL query). Query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select     id
from       address
connect by sameasid = prior id
start with id = 1
order by   id    --  if needed
;

 ID
---
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
 10
 11

8 rows selected.
```